# Hyper-v Machine shuts down unexpectedly, Hyper-V log shows an Error:"DM operation add for the virtual machine"

Tags: hyper-v, shutdown

This cause me a big production problems, please help me.
one virtual machine shutted down unexpectly.
The Hype-v log shows:
 DM operation add for the virtual machine 'XXXXName' failed with error: Unspecified error (0x80004005)  (Virtual machine ID 7EDDD39A-F963-4FAA-8854-6179B7611AC3).

could it be possible if nobody touch the Hype-v and DM error happened??? please tell me how to fix this problem.

Answer (score 1):

DM is "dynamic memory". Your virtual machine tried to add memory and failed. A human didn't trigger this, you've just run out of memory.

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/f60b2767-dbfc-41d0-8019-24039aab187d/dynamic-memory-issue-dm-add-fails-with-0x800705aa?forum=winserverhyperv

Edit: the reason it failed, the error code, is explained here. It's possible there was a permission problem trying to allocate more memory. But still, essentially, you ran out of memory.

https://appuals.com/solved-how-to-fix-error-0x80004005/